# RewriteEngine Folder Redirect

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, load-balancing

I am writing a rewrite rule to redirect all urls from `mysite.co.uk/en/` to `mysite.co.uk/`. I have the following I have written. Just would like someone to confirm it is correct for me and suggest possible improvements if any.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.co\.uk/$1 [NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com\.au/$1 [NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.co\.nz$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www\.mysite\.com\.nz/$1 [NC,R=301]
RewriteEngine off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research turns out I should be able to do just this:

`redirect 301 /en/ http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/`

`redirect 301 /en/ http://www.mywebsite.com.au/`

`redirect 301 /en/ http://www.mywebsite.co.nz/`

This we redirect any urls that are going to `www.mywebsite.co.uk/en/` or `mywebsite.co.uk/en/` to `www.mywebsite.co.uk/`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Please REPLACE domain.com and www.newdomain.com with your actual domain name.
```

Comment: I noticed you changed the ^en/(.*)$ to ^(.*)$ this doesn't account for the fact that I am setting this rule on a load balancer and the /en/ folder is not a physical folder its a logical one created by the cms.